# Populating drop down list with hours of the day razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to populate the dropdown list with hours of the day using razor (mvc 5). I used one of the examples I found:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.StartTime,
    Enumerable.Range(00, 24).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), "-- Hour --")
```

It shows the list, but as far as I understand since I used `.ToString()` it converted hours of the day (that I defined start time as integer in my model)
to string and suppressed all leading zeros. What method I can use to display hours in 24 hour format, and let's say I want my default to show instead of literal Hour some hour of the day, For example 06.

It is new language for me, and learning as I go.

Comment: Can you tell us what your model has?

Comment: public int StartTime { get; set; }

Comment: What is typeof `StartTime`? Unless its `int` this could not even bind correctly. Best guess is you want the property to be `TimeSpan` (and for the display text in the dropdownlist it needs to be `Text = i.ToString("{0:00}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the string with leading zeros.

```
6.ToString("D2");
// Output: 06
```

**For a default value:** (Not have been tested)

```
@{ string defaultValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.StartTime) ? "06" : null; }
@Html.DropDownListFor
(
    Model =>
        Model.StartTime,
        Enumerable.Range(00, 24).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }),
        "-- Hour --",
        defaultValue
)
```

Comment: what is the proper syntax for Output statement

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand the question.

Comment: you put //Output:06. isn't // represents the comment?

Comment: Yes, i just wanted to show you the expected result.

Comment: OKay, understood, but what I meant, I want the cursor position to be on 06 hour when the view is presented the first time, before any selection is made

Comment: I've edited my answer, but the code did not been tested, i believe you can take it from here.